# How can I allow to delete only for logged in users

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I'm trying to create a delete function that deletes a MySQL row only if that row was created by the same logged-in user.  So if the row is not created by that user, it cannot delete that row.

Here's what I have so far (Javascript):

```
app.post('/Update_Award', function(request, response) {
        var connection = request.app.get('pool');
        if (request.session.loggedin) {
            //delete query
        connection.query('SELECT username FROM accounts', [request.session.username], function (error, results, fields) {
            //if (results[0].username === request.session.username) {

            connection.query('DELETE FROM award WHERE id = ?', [request.body.id], function(error, results, fields) {
             //do something
            } else {
                console.log("No access");
            }
```

The MySQL table for accounts has "id" column and "username" column.  I want to make is so that only rows created by the same logged in user id can be deleted.

The rows created are identified by issuerID.  So I am deleting the rows by the row ID and the rows created by isserID.

Comment: Is there any column in your database that identities rows being created by a user like user_id or created_by anything like that?

Comment: Hi Prabhjot, I updated my post.

Answer (score 2):

You can change your code to

```
app.post('/Update_Award', function(request, response) {
  var connection = request.app.get('pool');
  if (request.session.loggedin) {
    connection.query('DELETE FROM award WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM accounts WHERE username = ?)', [request.session.username], function(error, results, fields) {
      if (//your condition) {
        //do something
      } else {
        console.log("No access");
      }
    })
  }
})
```

Comment: I keep getting error: 
Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

Comment: At first your select query is wrong. Which we used the same way. However, a table uses the IN statement to clear multiple rows simultaneously. In the meantime your query should not be keywords. And you should first test the query inside mariyaDB and get the row and column in that section.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like below.

```
app.post('/Update_Award', function(request, response) {
  var connection = request.app.get('pool');
  if (request.session.loggedin) {
    connection.query('DELETE FROM award WHERE id = ? AND issuerID IN (SELECT 
     id FROM accounts WHERE username = ?)', [request.body.id, 
    request.session.username], function(error, results, fields) {
      if (//your condition) {
        //do something
      } else {
        console.log("No access");
      }
    })
  }
})
```